# PyQt4: How to auto adjust size of a widget not in layout

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to implement a GUI program like the blueprint editor in the Unreal game engine with PyQt4. Here is an example of the blueprint editor:

[image]

First I create a simple container widget to place all the components(The rectangles). In order to allow the user place the rectangles wherever they want(by drag & drop), I can't place my widgets in a layout. Then when the content of the rectangle is changed, the rectangle widget can't auto adjust the size itself.

Following is an example code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class ChangeableChild(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChangeableChild, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        self.layout().addWidget(widget)


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, child, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        child.setParent(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    changeable_child = ChangeableChild()
    button = QtGui.QPushButton("Add label")
    changeable_child.addWidget(button)
    win = MainWidget(changeable_child)
    win.show()
    button.clicked.connect(
        lambda: changeable_child.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("A label.")))

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I hit "Add label" button to add a new label. The size of `ChangeableChild` wouldn't change automatically. If I put the `ChangeableChild` in a layout, it's all good.

So is there a way to auto adjust my widget when it's not in a layout? Or is there a way I can place my widget in a layout and still can place it in a absolute position?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail, what exactly it is you are trying to achieve? I'm fairly confident that you should be using layouts, but it is hard to know the exact behaviour you are after.

Comment: @three_pineapples I can't use layout because I need to place my widget in absolute position. Is there a layout allow me control the position, like place it in QPoint(10, 30), of the widgets in it?

Comment: You need to detail the exact behaviour you want. Which corner of the widget do you want fixed absolutely. How do you want it to expand/contract as the parent widget is resized. What about other widgets? How do you want those to behave. What is the point of offsetting it by `(10,30)` pixels? Why is that important? The more information you give, the easier it will be for someone to answer your question. At the moment, your minimal example seems pointless because you aren't even applying such an offset.

Comment: @three_pineapples I've updated the question, sorry about the misleading "absolute position", what I really mean is "arbitrary position" . But what I really care is how to auto adjust size of a widget not in layout, like what I said in the tile. I've searched a lot in google, can't find any layout in qt4 allow me to put my widget in arbitrary position.

Comment: For a UI like that, you should perhaps consider QGraphicsView or QML. But for widgets, override `resizeEvent` and resize/reposition child widgets there.

Comment: @hyde Thank you. It's very cumbersome to do drag and drop in `QGraphicsView` so I choose `QWidget`. About `resizeEvent`, I tried override the `resizeEvent` method of both `ChangeableChild` and `MainWidget` in the example. When the label is added into `ChangeableChild`, the `resizeEvent` isn't being called.